# Remote execution - 2 command outputs in same line

Tags: bash, shell

shell#printf "`hostname` `rpm -qa | grep rhncfg-actions`\n"
     usmnxbox01 rhncfg-actions-5.10.85-1.el6.noarch

I am trying the get the above output using ssh from multiple hosts using the command below.

```
for i in `cat ahosts`; do ssh -t $i "printf "`hostname` `rpm -qa | grep rhncfg-actions`\n"" 2>/dev/null;done
```

but I get the hostname of the system am I running this command on.

Comment: Your goal is probably easier to reach with [pdsh](https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/) or one of its alternatives

Comment: I don't want to deploy an agent or package to all the clients to run this command.

Comment: No deploying necessary, pdsh is just a parallel ssh client.  It does the same as your `for ... ssh` loop. Only easier and in parallel. Just check the website..

Comment: The issue is with the use of double quotes `"`. Replace them with single quotes and you are golden. Or escape the backticks if you prefer to use double quotes. Try this `for i in $(<ahosts); do ssh -t $i 'printf "%s %s\n" $(hostname; rpm -qa | grep rhncfg-actions)' 2>/dev/null;done`.

Comment: @alvits works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the command substitutions in single quotes to prevent them from being evaluated locally before being sent to the remote host. Your code also has several other problems:

1. Using a `for` loop to iterate over a file
2. Using command substitutions in the format string argument to `printf` (which causes problems if any of the substitutions contain a percent sign).

Use this instead:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    ssh -t "$i" 'printf "%s %s\n" "$(hostname)" "$(rpm -qa | grep rhncfg-actions)"' < /dev/null
done < ahosts
```

This redirects the standard input for `ssh` from `/dev/null` so that `ssh` doesn't incorrectly consume input meant for the `read` command.